# How to define a variable which can be used to store both a pointer-to-int and iterator-to-int-container?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, iterator, generic-programming

What is an appropriate type for type T below? I don't want to use auto because I want to create a class with a member variable of type T. Thanks.

```
int* ptr;
vector<int> vec;

T var = ptr;
T var2 = vec.begin();
T var3 = vec.end();

var++; var2++;         // T should be so that these are legal
T newvar = var2 + 5;   // Allow random access etc.
```

Based on a comment, here's what I want to do. I want to create a class to represent a graph in adjacency list form but abstract out the low-level underlying implementation detail.

```
// First implementation
vector<vector<int> > adj1; // adj1[i] gives vector of neighbors of i-th vertex
vector<int> nbrs_of_vertex_0 = {1,2};
vector<int> nbrs_of_vertex_1 = {2,0};
vector<int> nbrs_of_vertex_2 = {0,1};
adj1.push_back(nbrs_of_vertex_0);
adj1.push_back(nbrs_of_vertex_1);
adj1.push_back(nbrs_of_vertex_2);
int degree[3] = {2, 2, 2};

// Second implementation
int all_lists[6] = {1,2, 2,0, 0, 1};
int * adj2[3] = {all_lists, all_lists+2, all_lists+4};


// Common algorithm using both implementation
IteratorType it1 = adj[0].begin();
for(int i = 0; i < degree[0]; i++)
  cout << *it1++;
IteratorType it2 = adj2[0];
for(int i = 0; i < degree[0]; i++)
  cout << *it2++;
```

The question is: what should be type of IteratorType in above code?

Comment: There is no **standard** way to do this, but I think that your question is an example of XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - tell us what you want to do, not how have you tried to solve it and someone might be able to help you.

Comment: @TomaszKłak Edited the question per your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since c++11 you can use [begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [end](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) free function. Both of them work on both standard containers and "c arrays". And since we also have `auto` in c++11 you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
// Common algorithm using both implementation
auto it1 = std::begin(adj[0]);
for(int i = 0; i < degree[0]; i++)
  cout << *it1++;
auto it2 = std::begin(adj2[0]);
for(int i = 0; i < degree[0]; i++)
  cout << *it2++;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question right (and I'm not sure I am), then if you decide to use `int[]` internally, you can do

```
typedef int *Iterator;
```

and if you decide to use `vector<int>` internally you can do

```
typedef vector<int>::iterator Iterator;
```

and then use `Iterator` for all your algorithms and either typedef will work (since `*Iterator` will always be of type `int`), no rewriting required.

If instead you're worried about what people will pass in to your functions (they might pass in `int *` and they might pass in `vector<int>::iterator`), you make a templated function, and again as long as putting a * in front of what they pass in gives an `int` the function will work.

Comment: Yes, this does solve the problem. In particular, I can encapsulate the typedef in the graph class itself and the algorithm can access the typedef as follows: Graph::Iterator it = graph.neighbors(0); I wonder if c++ iterator class can be used instead somehow. Example: std::iterator<random_access_tag, int> ? Thanks for the answer!